# Two warring planets settling their differences on Earth secretly

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember a 70's sci fi TV feature. The premise of the show had two warring planets settling their differences on Earth secretly. They were to each send 4 or 5 agents who would battle to the last man and the winner would either win their war, or get Earth. The last guy had fallen for an earth woman who (surprise)...

> ...is an enemy alien in disguise, and kills him at the end.

Any idea what it might have been called?

Comment: Was this color, or black and white? Sounds like a Night Gallery episode.

Comment: *"(Sorry, should have said "spoiler alert")"*  Don't say anything, simply add a line break and prefix the spoiler with `>!`.

Comment: Fixed the spoiler thing for him.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211436/60s-70s-sci-fi-film-where-two-competing-alien-races-send-agents-disguised-as-hum (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

I saw this! Unmistakeable from the description. [The Love War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Love_War), a 1970 ABC Movie of the Week.

From the first line of the plot description on Wikipedia:

> Two warring planets agree to settle their conflict by each sending a trio of soldiers to Earth for a duel to the death. Disguised as human beings, they can only identify each other by using special visors.