# Sci-fi movie where aliens fight to control the Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie

Two group of aliens send their agents to Earth to fight over controlling Earth. These agents are in human form but can identify each other using special glasses. When an agent was killed, the killer used something like a wind key on his body and the body vanished.

The movie is from the 1960's to early 1970's.

Comment: Almost certainly a dupe of this question [60s-70s Sci-fi film where two competing alien races send agents disguised as humans to determine control of Earth (one side cheats)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/211441/20774) - The answer was "The Love War"

Comment: @Valorum , Thanks for your prompt response. I already searched before posting this, without success.

Comment: This is the exact answer I have been looking for many years!

Comment: [Always happy to help.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)